# Video play on scroll animation stuck on Google Chrome and some mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation, scroll, gsap

I hope anyone can help me with this animation on scroll video.

The scroll animation is working great with a video, as shown in this example:
[https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/vYKBPbv/9e810322d70c306de2d18237d0cb2d78][1]

However, when I use another video:
[https://codepen.io/ivis24/pen/XWyOGGm][2]

It gets stuck in Google Chrome for some reason. I hope someone has experience with this kind of problem?